# Did Magneto know that Apocalypse intended to kill Charles Xavier?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

In *X-Men: Apocalypse*, Apocalypse extends his lifespan by changing bodies, a procedure where he takes over the body and powers of his new host.

After being betrayed and buried deep into the earth in Egypt, the powers of Charles Xavier were extra useful for him since he'd never be betrayed (or caught off-guard) again.

For this, he kidnapped Charles Xavier and tried to move into his body. If he was to succeed, Xavier would die. Did Magneto know about it? Did he accept it as a necessary sacrifice for his revenge from mankind or was he not aware of Apocalypse's plan?

Comment: The question makes perfect sense in light of the fact that in First Class, Erik/Magneto abandoned his missiles midway through air and was the first to rush to aid of Charles Xavier, when Moira's bullet aimed at Erik ricocheted off due his magnetic powers and hit Charles instead. Erik and Charles had a special bond, they cared for one another too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Did Magneto know about it?

Well, it didn't seem in the movie that he did know the plan of Apocalypse. Charles is his old buddy and Magneto had no intentions to harm him.

> Did he accept it as a necessary sacrifice for his revenge from mankind.

It didn't seem so. He had rage with the mankind who killed his loved ones in his opinion. That's why he was with Apocalypse to destroy the world. Though he knew Apocalypse will need Charles Xavier for this, but he didn't know that Charles will die in the process.

In the end, you can see that he turns against Apocalypse when he saw his friends being in trouble. He rejoins them and helps defeating Apocalypse.

> **Apocalypse:** You betrayed me.
>
> **Magneto:** No, I betrayed them.